# How to calculate load flow/power flow in a DC grid?

Tags: power, dc, microgrid, power-flow-analysis

From my understanding this depends exclusively on the voltage level, but I have not found documentation about how this happens or is done.

- Is it purely based on KCL?
- Are there any tools or procedures to calculate the load flow or the active power flow in a DC network such as a DC microgrid?

Comment: Tools? What about a simulation tool?

Answer (score 1):

Quebec Hydro has some [Simulation](https://www.hydroquebec.com/international/en/technology/grid-simulation.html) tools for power grids and wind turbines for micro grids.

Mb Hydro has one  too, “If you can imagine it, you can simulate it” but not used it either.